# How to setup grid layout with mapped react bootstrap cards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am having problems displaying react bootstrap cards in a grid layout, what I want it to do is to have 3 cards per row, and as many rows as needed.

From what I've tried it seems the traditional CSS display:grid and grid-template-columns doesn't work for cards, because all my cards just ended up displaying in the first column.

So then I read the react-bootstrap layout section but am confused on how to apply it to my case, where I am generating the cards by mapping an array to it. I have no problems doing the column tags but don't know how I would go about doing the row tags, is there a way to add something to one in every x items?

I want to do something like if i had an iterator that keeps looping from 1 to 3 and when its 1 I want the to have the beginning row tag and when its 3 for the card to have the ending row tag.

I don't think this matters but here is the code of the mapping, the Comp simply generates a Card using those attributes

```
        const people = ppl.map((person) => {
        return (
            <Comp
                key={person.id}
                info={{
                    name: person.name,
                    title: person.title,
                    date: person.created_at,
                    link: person.url,
                    language: person.language
                }}
            />
        );
    });
```

How would i go about achieving this? The only way I have thought of is looping through the finished mapping and adding in row tags for one in every x column tags I see, but I'm assuming there has to be an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this sandbox where react-grid-layout is rendered to bootstrap screen. Here I have created a widget with React GridLayout, onchnage of widget layout same thing you can see in Bootstrap[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-build-bootstrap-hpbb5x)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable.